# r cumulative sum function, conditions

Tags: r, cumsum

I have a data frame in R , fairly large 600 rows/observations

one column is `patientId` NOT in numeric form,e.g ju89, ju87, so it's a factor column

one column is `remission` 1/0 where 1 means remission 0 means not remission

one column is `timefromdiagnosis`

now, from time from diagnosis patients go from 1 to 0, 0 to 0, 0 to 1 or 1 to 1

I want to add a column to the data frame where it is

- 1 when a patient has 0 in remission
- 2 when precisely a patient has 1 in remission and the last time he had 0 OR has 1 in remission and the last time he had 1 in remission OR has 1 in remission and it is his first observation
- 3 when a patient has 1 remission and the last 2 or more times had 1 in remission

I looked into doing this with cum sum in `plyr`, but it doesnt fit what i want to do or its not very clear how to adapt

the data frame is already sorted so that patient id's are adjacent to each other and for each patient time from diagnosis increases as you read down the data frame

I am unable to supply the dataframe due to confidentiality but here it what it looks like to clarify things

```
remission timefromdiag patientid ...(other variables)
```

This is the data with which I am starting:

```
patientId  timefromdiagnosis  remission
ju67       1.2                1
ju67       1.6                0
ju67       3                  0
ju88       1.5                1
ju88       2                  1
ju23       1.9                1
ju23       5                  0
```

And here is what I want to get, disease stage is the column i want:

```
patientId  timefromdiagnosis  remission  disease stage
ju67       1.2                1          2
ju67       1.6                0          1
ju67       3                  0          1
ju88       1.5                1          2
ju88       2                  1          2
ju23       1.9                1          2
ju23       5                  0          1
ju38       1.7                1          2
ju38       1.9                1          2 
ju38       3                  1          3
ju38       4                  1          3
ju38       5                  0          1
```

Note how patient `ju38` reaches 3 because he has had 3 consecutive remissions including the time now (remission last two times and now), he then stays at 3 because he simply has another remission, he then goes to disease stage 1 because he has a 0 in remission.

patient `ju88` has remission at t=2 and has had remission at last time t=1.5 but this is only two consecutive remissions including t=2, so he is at disease stage 2

patient `ju23` at t=1.9, has a 1 in remission and it is the first observation on him so he satisfies critieria for disease stage 2, if he had a 0 in remission he would be at disease stage 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the number of consecutive periods for which a patient has been in remission, resetting that counter whenever a patient comes out of remission. I think the run-length encoding of the remission variable is therefore of interest. You can compute it with the `rle` function:

```
dat$diseaseStage <- ave(dat$remission, dat$patientId, FUN=function(x) {
  ret <- unlist(lapply(rle(x)$length, function(y) c(rep(2, min(2, y)), rep(3, max(0, y-2)))))
  ret[x == 0] <- 1
  ret
})
dat
#    patientId timefromdiagnosis remission diseaseStage
# 1       ju67               1.2         1            2
# 2       ju67               1.6         0            1
# 3       ju67               3.0         0            1
# 4       ju88               1.5         1            2
# 5       ju88               2.0         1            2
# 6       ju23               1.9         1            2
# 7       ju23               5.0         0            1
# 8       ju38               1.7         1            2
# 9       ju38               1.9         1            2
# 10      ju38               3.0         1            3
# 11      ju38               4.0         1            3
# 12      ju38               5.0         0            1
```

Note that this works in the more complicated case where a patient comes into and out of remission multiple times:

```
dat2 <- data.frame(patientId=rep("x", 12), remission=rep(c(1, 0, 1, 0), each=3))
```

Using the same function, we get:

```
#    patientId remission diseaseStage
# 1          x         1            2
# 2          x         1            2
# 3          x         1            3
# 4          x         0            1
# 5          x         0            1
# 6          x         0            1
# 7          x         1            2
# 8          x         1            2
# 9          x         1            3
# 10         x         0            1
# 11         x         0            1
# 12         x         0            1
```

Note that it's insufficient to use `cumsum` in this case because it won't pick up on the fact that we came out of remission in lines 4-6.

Comment: thank you very much for your response, how did you arrive at the solution so quickly? could you explain the second and more lines in more detail, just out of interest :), what is y? what is x? why are we 'rep'ing things, i feel like a min max makes sense but don't quite get it

Comment: @RampageKyd R is a functional programming language, so I'm defining functions that operate on pieces of the data. The outer function takes pieces of the remission variable, calls them `x`, and then operates on them. The inner function take individual elements of `rle(x)$length`, calls them `y`, and operates on them.